# Execute a file using OS sampler in JMeter on a RHEL 8 Machine

Tags: jmeter

Have a .net core library Linux compatible on a Linux machine. I can execute it locally from terminal and getting the expected result. But while executing from JMeter using a OS sampler it is failing.

From Terminal: Running Fine

[image]

JMeter Settings:
[image]

Fetching the Response Body: (which should be 352 for example from the above terminal)
[image]

JMeter it is failing:
[image]

Check the file location and permission, everything is in place. What I have missed here any help ?

### After change:

I changed as suggested and still facing the issue,
[image]

Error details,
[image]

Comment: Try put the working directory in the suggested solution

Comment: Tried it, still it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to invoke a [shell](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0010.php) instead of trying to execute your command directly, something like:

[image]

Also if you open the OS Process Sampler in the [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) you will see the output or in case of failure the failure reason

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dimtri for quick reply, But still it is failing

Answer (score 0):

I guess you misinterpret both Dimtri and User729 comment, you need to add both places and it should work.

[image]